# Replace existing file using FileImageOutputStream

Tags: java, image, io, replace

I'm trying to replace a file after changing it's quality - the problem is I'm only able to create a new file, not replace the original. Here is the code I'm using:

```
private static void resize(String folder, String filename)
        throws IOException {

    BufferedImage imagem = ImageIO.read(new File(folder + "/" + filename));

    float quality = (float) 0.25;

    ImageWriter writer = (ImageWriter) ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName(
            "jpeg").next();
    ImageWriteParam iwp = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
    iwp.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
    iwp.setCompressionQuality(quality);
    File file = new File(folder + "/" + filename);
    FileImageOutputStream output = new FileImageOutputStream(file);
    writer.setOutput(output);
    IIOImage image = new IIOImage(imagem, null, null);
    writer.write(null, image, iwp);
    writer.dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For me it did not truncate the file, so the old file's content was still present after the new data. You have to make sure the file is emptied before manually.

I did it like this:

```
        try (FileOutputStream faos = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
            try (BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(faos)) {
                try (ImageOutputStream fios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(bos)) {
                    writer.setOutput(fios);
                    writer.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), iwp);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my computer (with Java 7) it worked fine replacing the original file. Check the file has the correct writing permissions

Comment: I'm currently trying it on windows and the permissions seem to be working fine, still wont change it :S

Comment: @user2430343 I tried again to save the output to a different file and it has different size than the replaced. I tried with an image of 606KB. When I replace it, still is 606KB, but opening it, it has lower quality. If I save the output to a different file, it has 39KB and the same compression than the one with 606 KB

Comment: just did it a 607KB and it worked fine, but without replacing it, got a 28kb result. Can you please explain how that happened. Thx in advance

Comment: @user2430343 I mean I did this test:
Take image A.jpg (606KB, 1024x768 RGB byte)
Set the output in your code to B.jpg
Execute and got an compressed image B.jpg (39KB, 1024x768 RGB byte)
Revert the change in the code to replace image -> Got compressed image (606KB, 1024x768 RGB byte)
A.jpg and B.jpg are equal pixel to pixel and both different from the original
Copy again the original image A.jpg

Comment: Well I know that happens, but do you have any hint why? I'm a little bit clueless about the reason of the problem. I would like it to replace the A with 39KB and same resolution. Once more thx for the attention!